# Why is the number of parameters not the same as the number of categorical variables?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, categorical-data

I use python to deal with a linear regression problem. And I use categorical variables to represent data, but the result of linear regression doesn't give coef of each categorical variable.

The function is

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

X = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,1,2]],columns=['X1','X2','X3'])
y = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=['Y'])

mod = ols('np.log(y+1) ~ C(X1)+C(X2)+C(X3)-1', data=pd.concat([X, y], axis=1))
results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

I use -1 to remove the intercept. X1, X2, X3 are categorical variables, and each of them has three values:1, 2 and 3.

The result is

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C(X1)[1]      -0.1386      0.260     -0.532      0.689      -3.448       3.171
C(X1)[2]       1.0486      0.147      7.111      0.089      -0.825       2.922
C(X1)[3]       0.5545      0.260      2.129      0.280      -2.755       3.864
C(X2)[T.2]     0.4159      0.102      4.071      0.153      -0.882       1.714
C(X2)[T.3]     0.3054      0.209      1.465      0.381      -2.344       2.955
C(X3)[T.2]     0.7432      0.255      2.910      0.211      -2.502       3.988
C(X3)[T.3]     0.4159      0.102      4.071      0.153      -0.882       1.714
```

But each of x1,x2,x3 has 3 values, so I think I should get 3*3=9 lines of results. But I only get 7. C(X2)[T.1] and C(X3)[T.1] are missing. If I add the intercept by changing the function as

```
mod = ols('np.log(y+1) ~ C(X1)+C(X2)+C(X3)', data=pd.concat([X, y], axis=1))
```

, the result is as below:

```
Intercept      0.6439      0.108      5.984      0.105      -0.723       2.011
C(X1)[T.2]     0.6193      0.116      5.328      0.118      -0.858       2.096
C(X1)[T.3]     0.6931      0.511      1.357      0.404      -5.798       7.184
C(X2)[T.2]     0.0246      0.143      0.172      0.892      -1.793       1.842
C(X2)[T.3]     0.0908      0.212      0.429      0.742      -2.598       2.780
C(X3)[T.2]     0.5285      0.245      2.161      0.276      -2.579       3.637
C(X3)[T.3]     0.0246      0.143      0.172      0.892      -1.793       1.842
```

It's still only 7 parameters in results. I want to get 9 parameters which include C(X1)[T.1], C(X2)[T.1] and C(X3)[T.1].
I know the intercept represent the situation that X1=0,X2=0 and X3=0, but can I get intercept for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

They are encoded implicitly as the "base" category: if `C(X2)[T.2]` is `0`  (iff and only if `X2!=2`) and `C(X2)[T.3]`  is `0 (X2!=3)` ,then the only possibility left is that `X2==1`. The same goes for X3. The only reason that X1 has all three categories is because you eliminated the intercept, usually the intercept would correspond to the case X1=1, X2=1, X3=1. In general when using statmodels if the intercept is included, and each categorical variable can have N possible categories, then you will end up with (N-1)*(number of categorical variables) number of parameters in your new encoding.

If you want to know the prediction for when X2=1, it would correspond to C(X2)[T.2]=0, C(X2)[T.3]=0.

Comment: Can I get 3 intercepts for each of X1=1,X2=1 and X3=1? So I can get 9 parameters.

Comment: No, you can only get one intercept. One way to see this is that if you have Y=a*(1)+b*(1)+cX Then the underlying features for a and b are collinear, in fact they are the same feature (the constant 1). Again, looking at the equation, there would be no way to uniquely determine a solution for a and b since a'=a+t b'=b'-t would also be a solution for any value of t that you choose.

Comment: Please note that in my example there are 3*3 permutations of categorical input variables and each of these permutations should have a corresponding parameter, because for each of these permutations there exists a set of samples and these samples can determine the value of the parameter corresponding to each permutation.

Comment: If intercept is omitted, then there should be 3*3-1=8 parameters, which is equivalent to the situation where one of the parameters is zero (e.g., a set of samples for certain permutation have zero mean dependent variable, if the model is linear regression). If there are less parameters than this, then this means that some of the parameters are determined by samples from multiple permutations.Another way to see this is to imagine that instead of having 3 categorical variables each having 3 categories, we could have 1 categorical variable with 9 categories.

Comment: Then, it's clear that we should have 9 parameters with intercept and 8 without it, although their meaning would be slightly different (these parameters would be sums of the parameters that we shall find in the case of 3 categories). Overall, I think this is a bug in statsmodels, but maybe this is how other regression libraries implement categorical variables as well?"

Comment: It is not a bug, it is deliberate and the standard dummy coding : see for example: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/  or https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/contrasts.html.